# sampling from posterior predictive distribution (stan vs inla)

Tags: r, mixed-models, rstan, rstanarm, r-inla

I'm trying to implement functions from `bayesplot` package on a `INLA` object and a little unsure of how to draw from the posterior predictive distribution. I think I almost have it but `rstan`  draws are more variable than the `INLA` ones.

In `rstan`, using the simplified example from `bayesplot` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesplot/vignettes/graphical-ppcs.html) I can:

```
library(bayesplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(rstanarm)
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)


#rstan model set up
roaches$roach100 <- roaches$roach1 / 100 # pre-treatment number of roaches (in 100s)
fit_poisson <- stan_glm(y ~ roach100 + treatment + senior, offset = log(exposure2), family = poisson(link = "log"), data = roaches,  seed = 1111,  refresh = 0) 


#In order to use the PPC functions from the bayesplot package we need a vector y of outcome values:
y <- roaches$y
#and a matrix yrep of draws from the posterior predictive distribution,
yrep_poisson <- posterior_predict(fit_poisson, draws = 500)
#then plot:
p1 <- bayesplot::ppc_dens_overlay(y, yrep_poisson[1:50, ])
p1
```

[image]

I want to replicate that plot on a `INLA` object. According to the `bayesplot` vignette you can do this as they have provided code to define a simple `pp_check` method that creates fitted model objects of class e.g. `foo`:

```
pp_check.foo <- function(object, type = c("multiple", "overlaid"), ...) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  y <- object[["y"]]
  yrep <- object[["yrep"]]
  stopifnot(nrow(yrep) >= 50)
  samp <- sample(nrow(yrep), size = ifelse(type == "overlaid", 50, 5))
  yrep <- yrep[samp, ]
  
  if (type == "overlaid") {
    ppc_dens_overlay(y, yrep, ...) 
  } else {
    ppc_hist(y, yrep, ...)
  }
}
```

To use `pp_check.foo` we can just make a list with `y` and `yrep` components and give it class foo:

```
x <- list(y = rnorm(200), yrep = matrix(rnorm(1e5), nrow = 500, ncol = 200))
class(x) <- "foo"
#create plot above:
pp_check(x, type = "overlaid")
```

**INLA**

```
#create same model but in inla:
library(INLA)
fit_poisson_inla <- inla(y ~ roach100 + treatment + senior, offset = log(exposure2), data = roaches,
           control.predictor = list(compute = T),
           family = "poisson")
```

`inla_object_name$marginals.fitted.values` returns a posterior predictive distribution for each `y`:

```
fit_poisson_inla$marginals.fitted.values
#so to get distribution for first oberservation:
fitted.Predictor.1 <- fit_poisson_inla$marginals.fitted.values[[1]]
```

I think repeatedly sampling from this would give me what I need but there are only 75 values (`dim(fitted.Predictor.1)` per observation used to create this distribution when in reality I would want to be sampling from a full range of values. I think we can do this (section 4.3 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.01248.pdf)) by using `inla.tmarginal` using linear predictor:

```
fitted_dist <- fit_poisson_inla$marginals.linear.predictor
#should i have used "inla.rmarginal(n, marginal)"?
marginal_dist <- lapply(fitted_dist, function(y) inla.tmarginal(function(x) {exp(x)}, y)) %>% map(~ as.data.frame(.) %>%  rename(., xx = x))
#resample 500 times
yrep_poisson_inla <- as.matrix(bind_rows(rerun(500, lapply(marginal_dist, function(x) sample(x$xx, 1)) %>% as.data.frame())))

#convert to class foo for pp_check
x <- list(y = y, yrep = yrep_poisson_inla[1:50, ])
class(x) <- "foo"
p2 <- pp_check(x, type = "overlaid")
#plot
ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1, nrow = 2, labels = c("rstan", "inla sample"))
```

[image]

**My question is how do I correctly get a matrix of draws from the posterior predictive distribution from this `inla` (`fit_poisson_inla`) object to pass into `pp_check`?** `yrep_poisson` produces discrete values while `yrep_poisson_inla` produces continuous values. There is a lot more variation in the `rstan` draws than `INLA` (second plot). Is what I have done correct and this is just some sampling issue or is it an artifact of the different methods? In more complicated examples the differences could be substantial.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you eventually found a solution to this but I'm also interested. In the source you linked, page 11, the authors mention using the function `inla.posterior.sample` but they don't exactly document how it can be used to achieve what they say it can achieve (which is, getting posterior predictive samples). It seems the authors imply marginals do not account for variability in hyperparameters and that may be a reason for the difference with stan here.

Comment: @mkln no I didn't find a solution but your suggestion does sounds reasonable. That may well be it

Comment: note that it depends on the model. in some models the hyperparameters' posterior variability won't make predictions change all that much